# Как установить в ArrayAdapter hashmap?

Tags: android, listview

У меня есть кастомный адаптер, наследующий `ArrayAdapter<String>`. Сейчас я спокойно могу добавить свой текст в `textview`, который находится в `item`-e `listview`. Я же хочу добавить в `item` еще один `textview`. Первый `textview` заполнять данными, из одного массива данных, а второй, соответственно из другого. Прочитав несколько статей, я понял что для этого можно использовать `HashMap`, но как именно его использовать, чтоб он заполнял мои `textview` я не понял. Заранее извините, если что то непонятно

Код адаптера:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements UndoAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;

   String items[] = {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"};
    public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        for (int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
            add(items[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_row_dynamiclistview, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview1)).setText(getItem(position)); // textview1, куда я могу устанавливать свои значения.
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("Пока что случайный текст");//textview, куда я хочу устанавливать значения

        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getUndoView(final int position, final View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.undo_row, parent, false);

        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getUndoClickView(@NonNull final View view) {
        return view.findViewById(R.id.undo_row_undobutton);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс **`Pair`** . Он для этого и сделан - хранить пару значений.

Полностью **ваш** код будет выглядеть так:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pair<String,String>> implements UndoAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;


    public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        add(new Pair<String,String>("item1","sub1"));
        add(new Pair<String,String>("item2","sub2"));
        add(new Pair<String,String>("item3","sub3"));
        add(new Pair<String,String>("item4","sub4"));

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_row_dynamiclistview, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview1)).setText(getItem(position).first); // textview1, куда я могу устанавливать свои значения.
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(getItem(position).second);//textview, куда я хочу устанавливать значения

        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getUndoView(final int position, final View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.undo_row, parent, false);

        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getUndoClickView(@NonNull final View view) {
        return view.findViewById(R.id.undo_row_undobutton);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно использовать не `HashMap`, а простой класс модели, который будет содержать 2 поля типа `String`, из которых вы и будете заполнять ваши `TextView`.
Выглядит примерно так:

```
class MyClass {
    public String firstText;
    public String secondText;
}


..........................

List<MyClass> myClassList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
//заполнение myClassList 


..........................


public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass> implements UndoAdapter {
..........................
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно использовать [SimpleAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html), [пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/107-urok-48-ispolzuem-simpleadapter), либо наследоваться от [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), передавать что хотите и отображать как хочется.

Comment: Дело в том, что я использую анимированый listview, который, не очень хорошо работает с BaseAdapter-ом и SimpleAdapter-oм.